# Image View not Wrapping Contents

Tags: java, android, imageview

I've got an ImageView wrapping [this image](http://www.oceannetworks.ca/sites/default/files/images/pages/maps/ONCMap_simplelabled.jpg):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/oncmap"/>
```

and right below it, a TextView. Unfortunately, it either pushes it down the view or out of the view depending on the device's screen size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0yo0.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/biNIW.jpg

I can "hack" it, but it'd rather not...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="MapFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/oncmap"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Neptune"
    style="@style/sectionHeader"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/info"
    style="@style/text"/>
```

Comment: the problem is not with ImageView, you should provide entire .xml document, maybe some weight issue or something.

Comment: If the image needs to be within bounds, why not set the height and width of the imageview along with scale type fitXY?

Comment: @DarkoRodic I've edited the original post with the full XML - I'm not using weights.

Comment: And why not use a RelativeLayout container - so that the textview position can be specified relative to the imageview's position?

Comment: use match_parent instead of wrap_content, and change the scaleType of your image to fitXY

Comment: @Srikanth the issue is that the imageview still has a whole bunch of "padding" at the bottom - even with a relative layout http://i.imgur.com/GpBDXr6.png

Comment: @Houcine this is the result http://i.imgur.com/q9bRCoE.png

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Add the following fields to ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: scaleType is not really needed. adjustViewBounds does the job. But can someone explain why this issue is happening?

Comment: @AjithMemana See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Answer (score 4):

To display **original image size** in Imageview write down following.
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` do the job. No need to set ScaleType.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/iv_QuestionImage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_app_icon_512"
     android:visibility="gone"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score -1):

if you try to add the large size image for eg let say 4~6 mb and you are using the drawable,then you would get the error like->**java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(537528960bytes) bitmap**

For java do this in your android studio, but the concept remains same for others also,do this to insert the image in your app in the background, applicable for both large and small size images.

**Basically move your image in the (hi-res) drawable to drawable-xxhdpi** which would be finded by going in the app->res->mipmap.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/imagename" />
```