# ImageView boundary out of control

Tags: android, imageview

I am using ImageView to show picture. However, for some pictures, the boundary of ImageView is bigger than the picture although i have set it as wrap_content. For example,

[image]

Here is my xml.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/image_16"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

How can i make sure the boundary is same size as the image?

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: @SamTwe are you sure your image does not have any transparent space at its boundary? Sometimes images will have transparent spaces around it :) So check your image once :)

Comment: I am quite sure as this is jpg format image and i have opened it to check

Comment: @Aspicas I have edited my post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21203321/3802077

Comment: take a look at android:scaleType = "fit_center" or other options how you want to fit image to boundaries.

Comment: Are you looking for `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`?

Comment: yup! Exactly is `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your ImageView xml tag

```
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

this will make sure that the image takes it's size without stretching

Comment: What i want is actually `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`. Thanks anyway